# Gae, webapp2 url with multiple parameters

Tags: google-app-engine, url, parameters, webapp2

I am currently work on a web app using webapp2, that deals with restaurant in several cities. Some of the url would look like

```
1. www.example.com/newyork
2. www.example.com/newyork/fastfood
3. www.example.com/newyork/fastfood/tacobell
```

To handle the first url, I used the following

```
CITY_RE = r'(/(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+/?)*)'

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([(CITY_RE, CityHandler)], debug = True)
```

How would I handle the url with multiple parameters such as 2 and 3.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar approach to match urls like `/<country>/<region>/<city>/<category>`e.g. `/usa/california/losangeles/restaurants` where I use this regex:

`app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/([^/]+)/?([^/]*)/?([^/]*)', RegionSearch)], config=settings.w2config, debug=True)`

The declare the relevant parameters in the handler class.

```
class RegionSearch(SearchBaseHandler):
    """Handles regional search requests."""

    def get(
            self,
            region=None,
            city=None,
            category=None,
            subcategory='For sale',
            PAGESIZE=50,  # items on page
            limit=60,  # number of days
            year=2012,
            month=1,
            day=1,
            next_page=None,
    ):
```

I think that you could even do it this way

`webapp2.Route('/passwdresetcomplete/<city>/<category>/<name>', handler=RegionSearch, name='regionsearch')`